# How to monitor UPnP communication?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, upnp

My computer is connected to a router that supports UPnP, however it's not the last router on the way to the WAN. So, mapping there has no effect.

I've got VPS and I've made a VPN network (computer <-> VPS). Now I've got two gateways, but GW using tunneled interface has lower metric, so everything goes through it.

I want to check whether some certain software maps (creates forwarding) for any port using UPnP. I want to monitor any event regarding UPnP (router discovery, port mapping request, etc.)